# Archive page is missing under new SE blog

Tags: feature-request, blog

The blog *used* to have **archive** page where one could browse the blog posts by a month of the year. The newly re-designed SE blog site is currently missing the archive section and the old [archive page URL](http://blog.stackexchange.com/archive/) gives the '**404 page not found**' error.

As per [Wayback Machine Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315015826/http://blog.stackexchange.com/archive/) the latest snapshot was taken on March 15, 2015. Here is the screenshot (top section) of the same.

> [image]

Would it be possible to reinstate the archive page please?

Comment: Urgh, blog archives. Aren't the posts on the blog just, blog posts, regardless of their age or when they were written? What determines an "archive" over "this was posted 8 years ago".

Comment: @James *What determines an "archive"* In typical blog usage, any date-based navigation for content. There's no longer any clear way to, say, browse for a post from 2012.

Comment: @James date-based archive is another way to explore the changes made in the early days of the site.